# Using cursor parameter results in a different execution plan?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

For some reason I'm trying to figure out why the following query executes by full table scan which takes ages because the table has ~31M rows

```
PROCEDURE d1(k_uni_in IN data_par.k_uni%TYPE) AS
  CURSOR d1_cur IS
  SELECT d.*
  FROM data_par d
  WHERE d.k_uni = k_uni_in
  ORDER BY d.k_date;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN d1_cur LOOP
    ...
  END LOOP;
END;
```

However seemingly similar query runs index range scan and is pretty much instant

```
PROCEDURE d1(k_uni_in IN data_par.k_uni%TYPE) AS
  CURSOR d1_cur(k_cv IN data_par.k_uni%TYPE) IS
  SELECT d.*
  FROM data_par d
  WHERE d.k_uni = k_cv
  ORDER BY d.k_date;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN d1_cur(k_uni_in) LOOP
    ...
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Why does that happen? Should I always use cursor parameters instead of using suprogram parameters in cursors?

Comment: The latter query isn't actually using the parameter that you're passing in so if that's actually representative of what you have, your choice of syntax isn't relevant.  Are you calling the two pieces of code with identical parameter values?  Is there a histogram on `k_uni` in `data_par`?  Is the data in this column actually skewed?  So if there are, say, 10 distinct values, do some have much more than 10% of the data and some have much less?  Or is the distribution more uniform?

Comment: I've made a typo in 2nd query, it actually does use cursor parameter. None of the `k_uni` values have more than 10% of the data, in fact there's only a few rows for each distinct `k_uni`. The queries I've posted always result in the same execution plans, no matter what value I'm passing

Comment: It doesn't make sense that a bind variable passed in as a cursor parameter would produce a different query plan than a bind variable passed in a a procedure parameter if the parameter value is the same and the query really is identical.  If you're saying that you've excluded bind variable peeking as the issue, can you post a reproducible test case that we can run that demonstrates the issue?  Something else is going on but it's hard to speculate about all the possible causes.  Is one query using some plan stability mechnaism, for example?

Comment: This is a longshot, but your DATA_PAR table doesn't happen to have a column named K_UNI_IN, does it?  If it did, that would explain it.

Comment: @Matthew McPeak Thank you, you're right, it does.. So what happens is that oracle self joins the table instead of using parameter value? Well I'd say that's counterintuitive.

Comment: Sometimes longshots pay off.  I'll write that up as the answer then, for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table DATA_PAR has a column named K_UNI_IN, then Oracle is interpreting this line:

```
WHERE d.k_uni = k_uni_in
```

As meaning

```
WHERE d.k_uni = d.k_uni_in
```

And, since that's obviously not a condition that an index can help with, you're getting a full table scan.

See also: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/nameresolution.htm#LNPLS2038